How to enable core library desugaring to be enabled for flutter_local_notifications for new declarative Plugin DSL syntax,
I coudn't find any information how ca I do that, I've tried to use the config from package but doesn't wordk. Any idea how can I do that? Please see my files:
My settings.gradle:
...

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.2.1" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
}

include ":app"


And my app/build.gradle:
    id "com.android.application"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "br.com.site10consultoria.bettao"
    compileSdk = 35
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
...

